# Can DFA's be directly constructed from some special regular expressions but not from general regular expressions?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

Ullman's Introduction to Automata, Languages and Computation constructs a NFA from a regular expression and then a DFA from the NFA.

Cormen's [Introduction to Algorithms](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecsli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap34.htm) has Section 32.3 for string matching by DFAs directly. I was wondering why it can  go  directly to DFA rather than indirectly via NFA? Is it because the string matching problem considered in Chapter 32 is all about finding occurrences of a string $P$ in another string $T$, so the regular expression is a special one $\Sigma^* P \Sigma^*$?

Can  DFA's be directly constructed from some special regular expressions but not from general regular expressions?

If yes, is the string matching algorithm by DFAs  in Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms a special version of the one for general regular expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of the relationship between algorithms: "A is a special version of B"? Without that, I don't believe this question can be answered. In any case, there are various "direct to DFA" algorithms; in addition to Brzozowski's algorithm mentioned by Bruan Scott, see R. McNaughton and H. Yamada. Regular expressions and state graphs for automata. IEEE Transactions on Electronic Computers, 9(1):39--47, March 1960. McNaughton&Hull's algorithm is also described in the Dragon Book.

Comment: When you have an algorithm for a problem, and when you apply the algorithm to  some of the problem's instances,  sometimes the algorithm can be simplified. I call the simplified version of algorithm as "a special version of" the original algorithm.

Comment: But what is a "simplified version"? Is it necessarily the result of some practitioner modifying the algorithm, which seems to be inherent in your description? Or could it be that an independently created algorithm, perhaps written with a different vocabulary, happens to somehow produce the same result in a manner which can objectively be characterised as a "simplification"? In the latter case, how can we precisely characterise the relationship?

Comment: "the simplified version of algorithm" is "the original algorithm. "

Comment: If intentionality is part of the definition, then it is certain that the algorithm in Cormen is not a special version of Brzozowski's algorithm, since it was not first produced as a simplification, and it is certainly not the same text.

Comment: But that doesn't rule out the possibility that two programs, one implementing algorithm Brz and the other implementing algorithm Cor, might not happen to execute the same steps except that one implementation happens to do additional work which has no useful result (such as evaluation of conditions which happen to be false, or loop limits which happen to be empty.) Proving that not to be the case is more difficult. I've never attempted such a proof so I couldn't say whether it is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms for constructing a DFA directly from any regular expression; one, based on Janusz Brzozowski’s notion of derivatives of regular expressions, is described (with an example) in [this PDF](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/turon/re-deriv.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Is the string matching algorithm by DFAs  in Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms a special version of the DFA one for general regular expressions?

Comment: @Tim: I’ve only a passing acquaintance with the field and simply don’t know, I’m afraid; Stack Overflow might be a better place to ask.